# C++ compiling error when calling a constructor within other constructor's call

Tags: c++

I have a C++ code that seems to be confusing a class contructor like `A::A(B b)` with a constructor that receives a function pointer, like `A::A(B (*)())`. Let me explain:

The following code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

struct Item {
  Item() {
    std::cout << "ITEM::Normal constructor\n";
  }
};

struct Container {
  Container(Item i) {
    std::cout << "CONTAINER::Normal constructor\n";
  }

  void doSomething() {
    std::cout << "Do something\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Container c3(Item());
  return 0; 
}
```

But if I add a call to `B::doSomething()`, like the following code, I obtain a compiler error that I don't understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

struct Item {
  Item() {
    std::cout << "ITEM::Normal constructor\n";
  }
};

struct Container {
  Container(Item i) {
    std::cout << "CONTAINER::Normal constructor\n";
  }

  void doSomething() {
    std::cout << "Do something\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Container c3(Item());
  c3.doSomething();
  return 0; 
}
```

The compiling error is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:6: error: request for member ‘doSomething’ in ‘c3’, which is of non-class type ‘Container(Item (*)())’
   c3.doSomething();
```

Comment: You should google for "C++ most vexing parse"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a veiled *most vexing parse issue*:

```
Container c3(Item());
```

declares a *function prototype*, and your helpful compiler issues the appropriate diagnostic.

```
Container c3{Item()};
```

is the fix.